# javascript - directly 'transfer' images to other objects

Tags: javascript, image, position, runtime

I was thinking that when you create another image object with the same class, it will download the image file again from the url. If I make an image object and save the actual image file in the memory, then use that to set new object image `src`, will that save time? Is it even possible? my game will have several objects that will have the same image file.

```
var imgtemplate = new Image();
imgtemplate.src = "my url";

var newimg = new Image();
newimg.src = imgtemplate.src;
```

Does the above code work or does it just transfer the "my url" string?

Comment: Did you try it? If so, what happened?

Comment: The browser will cache the image. There is no need to get too fancy.

Comment: @ultranaut interesting... i swear it didnt work before.